# Testing Sveltekit application with vitest / svelte testing

Tags: unit-testing, sveltekit, vitest, svelte-testing-library

I am struggling to set up basic unit tests for my Sveltekit application. I have two cases which I can't figure out:

- <strike>I'd like to test if a component throws an `error` (`@sveltekit/error`)</strike>
- <strike>I'd like to test if a component calls `new YT.Player` (which isn't imported but instead added to the globals by the library)</strike>

usually I would just mock YT and error respectively and check for `hasBeenCalled()` but for some reason I cannot get it to work and the documentation for vitest/sveltekit seem somewhat thin.
Any help would be really appreciated!

**EDIT:** I figured the first part out:

```
expect(() =>
    render(Component, {
        props: { foo: "bar" }
    })
).toThrowError();
```

**EDIT2:** Here's the second part. I hope it helps someone

```
const mockedPlayer = vi.fn();
const mockedYt = {
    Player: mockedPlayer.mockImplementation(() => {
        return { destroy: vi.fn() };
    })
};
vi.stubGlobal("YT", mockedYt);
```